# Django textfield can't pass validation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to validate users input before accepting a form. I don't want users to input urls in the textfield of my form. I wrote a custom validation code but it's not working and I'm not getting any error too.

```
message_body=models.TextField(validators=[validate_thread_field])
```

Validators.py

```
def validate_thread_field(value):
    cd= ('www','com','.net',)
    if str(cd) in value:
        raise ValidationError(u'dont play smart')
```

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str(cd)` is `"('www', 'com', '.net')"`. You probably want to to exclude values that contain any of the strings in `cd`:

```
if any(x in value for x in cd):
    raise ValidationError(u'dont play smart')
```